# Positive definite and semi definite in non linear programming

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization

How can I prove the following.
 Suppose that A is  a square matrix and suppose that there is another matrix B such that $A=B^TB$.

a)Show that A is positive semi definite

b)Show that if B has full column rank then A is positive definite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To part (a),  $z^TB^TBz$ is the sum of the squares of the entries in $Bz$.